# Ruby - how to read first n lines from file into array

Tags: ruby

For some reason, I can't find any tutorial mentioning how to do this...
So, how do I read the first n lines from a file?

I've come up with:

```
while File.open('file.txt') and count <= 3 do |f|
  ...
    count += 1
  end
end
```

but it is not working and it also doesn't look very nice to me.

Just out of curiosity, I've tried things like:

```
File.open('file.txt').10.times do |f|
```

but that didn't really work either.

So, is there a simple way to read just the first n lines without having to load the whole file?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is a one-line solution:

```
lines = File.foreach('file.txt').first(10)
```

I was worried that it might not close the file in a prompt manner (it might only close the file after the garbage collector deletes the Enumerator returned by File.foreach).  However, I used `strace` and I found out that if you call `File.foreach` without a block, it returns an enumerator, and each time you call the `first` method on that enumerator it will open up the file, read as much as it needs, and then close the file.  That's nice, because it means you can use the line of code above and Ruby will not keep the file open any longer than it needs to.

Comment: I was not familiar with `IO::foreach`.  As it returns an enumerator, which can be combined with other enumerators, allows the use of `next` and `peek`, can be used to process just the beginning of a file, as you have, etc., it looks pretty useful. I don't understand your concern when just reading from a file. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I did my test with `strace` and found out it that everything was OK.  I was just worried that Ruby might leave the file handle open longer than necessary because I wasn't sure how it would know when the user is done reading lines from the file, and that leaving the file handle open for an unpredictable amount of time could cause bad side effects.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways you can approach this problem in Ruby. Here's one way:

```
File.open('Gemfile') do |f|
  lines = 10.times.map { f.readline }
end
```

Comment: You can use `f.lineno` instead of using a counter here.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I simplified my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
File.foreach('file.txt').with_index do |line, i|
    break if i >= 10
    puts line
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html) inherits from IO and IO mixes in [Enumerable methods which include `#first`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-first)

Passing an integer to `first(n)` will return the first n items in the enumerable collection. For a File object, each item is a line in the file.

```
File.open('filename.txt', 'r').first(10)
```

This returns an array of the lines including the \n line breaks. 
You may want to [`#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-join) them to create a single whole string.

```
File.open('filename.txt', 'r').first(10).join
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following:

```
`head -n 10 file`.split
```

It's not really "pure ruby" but that's rarely a requirement these days.